# lock on a static or instance variable in an abstract class

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety, locking, abstract-class

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    private static readonly object _filelockStatic = new object();
    private readonly object _filelock = new object();

    public void StaticLock()
    {
        lock(_filelockStatic)
        {
             //Edit a common text file (common to all children)
        }
    }

    public void InstanceLock()
    {
        lock(_filelock)
        {
             //Edit a common text file (common to all children)
        }
    }
}
```

If I have an abstract class with a method that edits a text file (one text file common to all child class instances), to make it thread safe do I have to lock on a static member or does it not matter?

In other words **in the example code above is there a difference between `InstanceLock()` and `StaticLock()` in terms of thread safety?**

Comment: If the class *wasn't* `abstract`, do you already know the answer to this question? Compared with a non-abstract class that serves as a base class to other classes?

Comment: Not really... I assume that the "locking" member needs to be static but I couldn't find 100% confirmation when googling so I thought I'd post to be 100% sure. But also, is the static lock good enough? But sure, the `abstract` has nothing to do with it, more just to illustrate that the class will be inherited from

Comment: @Dan: "is the static lock good enough" - you should post the criteria.

Comment: @Dennis will it prevent a race condition on editing the common text file when the derived classes call the `StaticLock()` method in a multithreading environment?

Comment: @Dan yes it will, the static variable is the same from any thread as long as it stays in the App domain, see the link I added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference, since the `InstanceLock` will let two instances of derived classes edit the file at the same time. That is because the lock is not shared between the instances. Prefer the static lock as it will prevent any derived class from entering the `lock(_filelockStatic)` area from different threads as long as you are in [the same app domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
var o1 = new DerivedClass();
var o2 = new DerivedClass();

// o1._filelock != o2._filelock 
// o1._filelockStatic == o2._filelockStatic
```